# show that the function $\{x_n\}\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}x_n$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This problem comes from an old Preliminary exam:

Consider the space $[0,1]\times [0,1]\times \cdots$ (the countably infinite product of $[0,1]$ with the product topology) An element of $X$ may be thought of as a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with each $x_n\in [0,1]$ Show that the function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(\{x_n\})= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}x_n$$
is continuous.

So, basically, I need to show that, given an open set $G\subset \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(G)$ is open in the product topology. That is, $f^{-1}(G)$ can be written as a union of sets of the form $\prod_{i=1}^\infty H_i$ where each $H_i$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ and $H_i\ne [0,1]$ for only finitely many $i$. Since $f(X)=[0,1]$, I think it should suffice to show that if
$$G_1(a,b), \ \text{ where } \ 0\le a \le b \le 1$$
$$G_2=[a,b), \ \text{ where } \ 0= a \le b \le 1$$
$$G_3=(a,b], \ \text{ where } \ 0\le a \le b = 1$$
then $f^{-1}(G_i)$ is open in the product topology for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: Much easier: $\{ x_n\} \mapsto x_k$ is continuous for every $k$. Uniform convergence.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm trying to learn. Is it fine to prove it by showing the Hilbert cube metrizable by $\sum 2^{-n} |x_n- y_n|$ then showing the metric $d(\{0\},\{x_n\})$ is continuous?

Comment: @Rubertos If you mean "metrizable by $d(\{x_n\},\{y_n\}) = \sum 2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert$", then yes, that is fine. Showing that that metric induces the product topology is however stronger than showing the continuity of $f$ here. But sooner or later one should prove that such a construction induces the product topology on a product of countably many metric spaces. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1326002/compatibility-of-topologies-and-metrics-on-the-hilbert-cube).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you! {}{}

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* :$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}$

is a power of geometric series is already convergent and $\{ x_n\} \mapsto x_k$ is

continuous for every $k$ ( Uniform convergence).

pleas look [Cauchy_condensation_test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)